# Depth First Search Vrs Recursion for deletion

Tags: grails, recursion, groovy, depth-first-search

I am using an iterative method to delete a folder and all its children. So if Folder A gets deleted then all its children i.e b,c,d,e,f get deleted also.

What I have works as I have tested it quite a bit, but I'm not sure if it should be done more efficiently using recursion? Should I use it, in the long run my database could be quite large meaning performance will be an issue in the future.

```
        int thisId = params.int('thisId')
        def datafile = Datafile.get(thisId)
        int parentId = datafile.parent_id 
        boolean continueIteration = true
        List<Datafile> itemsToBeDeleted = new ArrayList<Datafile>();
        Set<Datafile> folderfileList;
        Set<Datafile> tempfolderfileList = new HashSet<Datafile>();
        Set<Datafile> temp;
        List<Datafile> initialDatafileList = Datafile.findAllByParent_id(thisId)
        itemsToBeDeleted.add(Datafile.findById(thisId))
        for(int i=0; i<initialDatafileList.size(); i++){
            continueIteration = true;
            System.out.println("1st   "+initialDatafileList.get(i).id)
            folderfileList = Datafile.findAllByParent_id(initialDatafileList.get(i).id)
            itemsToBeDeleted.add(Datafile.findById(initialDatafileList.get(i).id))
            while(continueIteration) {
                if(folderfileList.size() >=1){
                    for(Datafile df: folderfileList){
                      // System.out.println("2nd   "+df.id)
                        temp = Datafile.findAllByParent_id(df.id)
                        for(Datafile z: temp ){
                          System.out.println("temp    "+z.id)
            }
                        if(temp.size()>=1){
                            tempfolderfileList.addAll(temp)
                        }
                        temp.clear()
                    }
                }
                else{
                    continueIteration = false
                }
        for(Datafile y: folderfileList ){
//                System.out.println("see if they are here   "+y.id)
            }
                itemsToBeDeleted.addAll(folderfileList)
                folderfileList.clear();
                folderfileList.addAll(tempfolderfileList); //changed from =
                tempfolderfileList.clear();
            }
        }
        for(Datafile y: itemsToBeDeleted ){
                System.out.println("deleted   "+y.id)
            }
        itemsToBeDeleted*.delete(flush:true)
```

Comment: It seems your current approach is to collect the files during the DFS traversal and to delete them all at once at the end. From a memory consumption point-of-view, it would of course be more efficient to remove each file immediately and each directory as soon as all of its descendants have been removed. However, the code you posted has some formatting problems and lacks comments describing your intention at each part. Without fixing these issues, it is difficult to read your code, which makes it difficult to say what exactly has to be changed in your code to achieve the desired result.